# Command Injection using Java's getRuntime().exec() does not seem to work properly

Tags: java, command, code-injection

I'm practicing some command injection via runtime exec in Java. For some reason this code doesn't seem to work, and I've been trying to figure it out for several hours now.

```
import java.net.*;

class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // url object
        URL url = null;

        try {
            // create a URL
            url = new URL(
                    "https://google.com;/usr/bin/touch pizza.txt");

            // get the ExternalForm
            String _ExternalForm = url.toExternalForm();

            // display the URL
            System.out.println("URL = " + url);

            // display the ExternalForm
            System.out.println("\nString representation= "
                    + _ExternalForm);

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash " + _ExternalForm);

        }
        // if any error occurs
        catch (Exception e) {

            // display the error
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

_ExternalForm is a string and it get concat'd to /bin/bash. I've tried all sorts of injections with semicolons, &, |, etc. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, could you tell us what is the purpose of this code? The URL path looks strange to me. What is semicolon ";" doing there? Why the empty space between "touch" and "pizza"? Last, are you sure such file exists at Google?

Comment: I'm injecting code to exploit getRuntime().exec()'s lack of sanitization on the _ExternalForm variable. When executed the command will be `/bin/bash https://google.com;/usr/bin/touch pizza.txt` which should create the file pizza.txt, but I've tried all sorts of stuff and it doesn't work.